# Remotely enable a laptop's airplay from an Apple TV

Tags: swift, lan, apple-tv, airplay

Any suggestions for how you would "trigger" the airplay on a Macbook Air laptop to start mirroring to an Apple TV?

The setup is as follows:

1. laptop is connected to LAN
2. Apple TV (called "Living Room") is also connected to LAN

I can write an osascript to start the airplay **from** the laptop **to** the Apple TV:

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "SystemUIServer"
    click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "Displays")
    set displaymenu to menu 1 of result
    click ((menu item 1 where its name starts with "Living Room") of displaymenu)
  end tell
end tell
```

However, I want to have a button (or simple app) on the apple tv that triggers this code, but I'm not sure what's the best way to go about this.

I know there's a bit of software called Remote Buddy, but I'd like something more simple if possible.